# "tops" meaning "props" or "kudos"

Tags: word-usage, slang

I recently heard "tops" used in a way similar to "kudos" and "props".

> Kid 1: Hey Palet, **tops** on your strategy man.
>
> Kid 2: What strategy?
>
> Kid 1: You know, start off with the psycho whore and work you way up from there. Yeah I just hope you're banging her by now. Trust me it doesn't take half the work you're putting in. (source: movie *The Bachelors (2017)*)

I have never heard tops used this way. I would have said "kudos on your strategy". I wonder if this is a real-world slang usage and if it has any currency in teenspeak. Or is it a misuse where "kudos" should have been used? Actual hits of this usage on Google are (vanishingly) rare.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like slang I've not heard but is quite clear from the context. It could be from 'Top marks' being the highest grade. Certainly some abbreviated form of 'Top credit', 'Top value', 'Top rating'.  The year 2017 would indicate a recent contrivance.

Comment: +1 makes sense.